# Troubleshooting IntelliJ communication issues

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ fails to communicate with a remote Tomcat instance. Is there a way to obtain verbose communication logs of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this issue comments](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88167) for the instructions from Michael Golubev how to enable additional logging via `log.xml` modifications.

For low level network debugging you can use something like WireShark.